# How to toggle the Status Bar on/off?

Tags: iphone, statusbar

I have a situation where I sometimes need a real fullscreen view that also covers the status bar completely. When this view is gone, I want the status bar to be visible again below it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES/NO withAnimation: UISatusBarAnimation];
```

Comment: the `withAnimation` part doesn't take a `BOOL`. it takes a `UISatusBarAnimation` enum. Options listed [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIStatusBarAnimation)